# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getSubCategories

Tags: php, prestashop-1.5

My shop is built with Prestashop 1.5.6.2.

On a error log file on my server, I can see the following error about 10 times a day :
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSubCategories() on null in ../controllers/front/ProductController.php on line 551

On the line 551 of the ProductController.php file is :

```
 'subCategories' => $this->category->getSubCategories($this->context->language->id, true),
```

This line is part of the following code :

```
// various assignements before Hook::exec
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'path' => $path,
        'category' => $this->category,
        'subCategories' => $this->category->getSubCategories($this->context->language->id, true),
        'id_category_current' => (int)$this->category->id,
        'id_category_parent' => (int)$this->category->id_parent,
        'return_category_name' => Tools::safeOutput($this->category->name),
        'categories' => Category::getHomeCategories($this->context->language->id, true, (int)$this->context->shop->id)
    ));
```

I am not a developer and I do not know what could lead to this error.

Would you have any idea of what could make this error ?

Thank you in advance for your any reply.

Patrick

Comment: This error means that `$this->category` is null, check it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming because the **`$this->category`** variable is not defined in some cases.
You should add a condition to check that in code **`(controllers/front/ProductController.php on line 551)`**

Replace the following

```
'subCategories' => $this->category->getSubCategories($this->context->language->id, true),
```

with

```
'subCategories' => Validate::isLoadedObject($this->category) ? $this->category->getSubCategories($this->context->language->id, true) : array(),
```

See if the issue is fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much Knowband for your last suggestion. Your method works perfectly !